# Formvalidation addField doesn't do anything

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, formvalidation-plugin

I'm using [formvalidation.io](http://formvalidation.io) to validate a form in Bootstrap. The form has a dynamic field option, so I am trying to use the addField functionality to make sure that this field is included when the form is validated. As explained [here](http://formvalidation.io/examples/adding-dynamic-field/). Unfortunately this doesn't work. The new fields are never included in the validation.

Script to add a new button:

```
$(document).on("click", '#add-row', function() {
   var rownr = parseInt($(this).attr("data-rownr"));
   rownr = (rownr+1).toString();
   $(this).attr("data-rownr", rownr);
   var rowid = '#contact-rule-'+rownr;
   $(this).before("<input type='text' id='"+rowid+"' name='"+rowid+"'/></div>");
   $option = $(document).find(rowid);
   $('#ruleForm').formValidation('addField', $option);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked around this by adding all fields in code upfront und making then hidden and using javascript to make them visible again. Also set Formvalidation to exclude hidden fields.